# Putting functions from Multiple Threads into a Single Queue

Tags: java, multithreading

i am creating a library simulator which has inside a Library, a Librarian and multiple Borrower Objects. It involves multiple Borrower Threads and a single librarian thread that run concurrently, performing tasks like requesting books, returning books etc.

I have been using Synchronized functions to ensure that the functions within each Borrower do not become muddled, but now i am trying to figure out how instead to, once a Borrower begins a function, to put it into a queue with a set sleep between entries, and that the output will be posted to the console within intervals.

My question is once a Borrower gets to a function e.g. RequestBooks, instead of simply outputting it into the console, and due to the fact that there are multiple Borrowers, is there any way that i can put the output of the function or the Borrower executing the function within a queue, so that, say, every 3 seconds, the queue processes an entry, then runs the function so that the output for each function put into the queue prints out in even intervals.

At some point i will be using a Lock system (Which i am also unsure of how to execute over the multiple Threads) which will dictate which Borrower sends a function to the queue, if that helps any confusion.

The Borrower code is below :

```
public class Borrower extends Thread {

private int noOfBooks;
private Set<Book> BooksBorrowed;
private Set<Integer> booksRequested;
private int id;
private int runs;
private Library library;
private Random randSleep = new Random();

public Borrower(int id, Library library, int runs) {

    this.library = library;
    this.id = id;
    this.runs = runs;
    noOfBooks = 1;

    }

public Borrower(){}

public String getLoans() {
    String output = "";
    for(Book b : BooksBorrowed) {
        output +=" "+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }
    return output;
}

public void run()
{   
    try {
        Initialize();

        for(int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            RequestBooks();
            ReturnBooks();
        }

    } finally {}
}

public synchronized void Initialize() {

    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    Random r = new Random();
    noOfBooks = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" Starting");

    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void RequestBooks () {

    Random r2 = new Random();
    Book temp = null;

    ArrayList<Book>books = new ArrayList<Book>(library.getBooks());
    ArrayList<Integer>Chosen = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < noOfBooks; i++){
        int index = r2.nextInt(books.size());
        temp = books.get(index);
        int tempId = temp.getBookId();
        Chosen.add(tempId);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("\nBorrower "+id+" requests " +noOfBooks+" Books from Library ");

    booksRequested = new HashSet<Integer>(Chosen);

    String requestedBooks = "";

    for(Integer bookid : Chosen) {
        requestedBooks = requestedBooks+bookid+" ";
        booksRequested.add(bookid);

    }
    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" request Books: "+requestedBooks);

    BooksBorrowed = library.RQST(id,booksRequested);
    ArrayList<Book> chosenBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    chosenBooks.addAll(BooksBorrowed);

    System.out.println("Books requested by Borrower "+id+" : "+requestedBooks+"\n");

    String receivedBooks = "";
    Book[]BookArray = BooksBorrowed.toArray(new Book[BooksBorrowed.size()]);
    for(Book b : BookArray) {
        receivedBooks = receivedBooks+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }

    System.out.println("Borrower "+id+" Books recieved :"+receivedBooks);
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    notifyAll();

}

public synchronized void ReturnBooks() {
    Set<Integer> BooksReturned;
    ArrayList<Integer> returningBooks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String returnedBooks = "";
    ArrayList<Book> borrowed = new ArrayList<Book>(BooksBorrowed);

    for (Book b : borrowed) {
        returningBooks.add(b.getBookId());
        returnedBooks = returnedBooks+b.getBookId()+" ";
    }

    BooksReturned = new HashSet<Integer>(returningBooks);

    library.RTRN(BooksReturned);
    System.out.println("\nBorrower "+id+" returned books to library: "+returnedBooks+"\n");
}
```

Here is the librarian code :

```
public class Librarian extends Thread {

Library library;
int runs = 0;

public Librarian(Library library, int runs) {
    this.library = library;
    this.runs = runs;

}
public ArrayList<Book> AddBooks() {  
    ArrayList<Book> addbooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    addbooks.add(new Book("The Lord of the Rings, The Fellowship",1,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Lord of the Rings, Two Towers",2,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Lord of the Rings, Return of King",3,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Hunger Games",4,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("A Game of Thrones",5,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("Storm of Swords",6,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Eagles Lair",7,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Philosophers Stone",8,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("Programming in Java",9,2));
    addbooks.add(new Book("Hit and Run",10,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The man in the Iron Mask",11,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("A Dance With Dragons",12,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("A Feast for Crows",13,5));
    addbooks.add(new Book("Jack the Ripper",14,1));
    addbooks.add(new Book("The Oddessey",15,1));

    return addbooks;


}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        //Random rsleep = new Random();
        Initialize();

    for(int i = 0;i < runs; i++) {

        //sleep(rsleep.nextInt(10000));
        getBorrowers();
    }

    } catch(Exception e){}
}

public void Initialize(){
    System.out.println("\nStarting Librarian");
    System.out.println("Library Initializing\n");
}

public void LibraryStatus() {

}

public void getBorrowers() {
    System.out.println("\nGetting Current Borrowers\n");
    String BorrowedBooks ="";
    Set<Entry<Integer,Set<Book>>> tempset = library.getBorrowers().entrySet();
    for(Entry<Integer,Set<Book>> entry : tempset) {

        for(Book b : entry.getValue()) {
            BorrowedBooks = BorrowedBooks + b.toString()+""; 
        }

        System.out.println("Borrower "+entry.getKey()+" borrowed books : "+BorrowedBooks);
        BorrowedBooks ="";
    }
}

public void setLibrary(Library library2) {
    this.library = library2;

}
```

}

And here is the main class that controls the others :

```
public class LibraryModel {

Library library = new Library();
Librarian librarian;
ArrayList<Borrower> BorrowArray = new ArrayList<Borrower>();
int runs = 0;
int isFinished;
Boolean isActive = true;


public LibraryModel() {
    library.AddBooks();

}

public static void main(String[]args) 
{
    int borrowCount = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Library Simulator\n");


    LibraryModel model = new LibraryModel();

    char quit = 'y';
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(quit != 'q')  {
        System.out.println("\n[S = start, A = About, Q = quit]");

        String a = sc.next();

        switch (a) {

            case "S":
                model.isActive = true;
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of Borrowers\n");
                borrowCount = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter how many runs the Program will run");
                model.runs = sc.nextInt();
                model.isFinished = model.runs;

                model.librarian = new Librarian(model.library,model.runs);


                    for(int i = 0 ;i < borrowCount; i++) {
                        model.getBorrowers().add(new Borrower(i+1,model.getLibrary(),model.runs));
                    }
                    model.librarian().start();

                    for(Borrower b : model.getBorrowers()) {
                        b.start();
                    }

                    try {
                model.librarian.join();
                for(Borrower b : model.getBorrowers()) {
                    b.join();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

            case "A":
                break;

            case "Q" :
                quit = 'q';
                break;

            default :
                System.out.println("Incorrect Entry, please enter a correct");
                break;
            }
    }   
}

public Library getLibrary() {
    return library;
}

public ArrayList<Borrower> getBorrowers() {
    return BorrowArray;
}

public Librarian librarian() {
    return librarian;
}


public int runs() {
    return runs;
}
```

}

Thankyou in advance for the help

Comment: Can you modify your question to explain it in better terms? I am really not able to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: Ok bot, ive updated the question, i hope this helps

Comment: Are all the borrowing threads communicating with one single librarian thread? Do you really need a librarian thread? That will really hammer your concurrency.

Comment: the borrowing threads do not really communicate with the librarian thread, The librarian threads purpose is simply to, at a random time,ask the library for a list of all the borrowers and which books they are borrowing at that certain point. It does not directly communicate with the Borrower, but it needs to run concurrently with them if you know what i mean

Comment: You can use RabbitMQ kind of message queues, which are well known open source libraries. Then you can use the messages anytime you want.